# Cargar una librería con $.getScript, pero metida en el head? Es posible?

Tags: jquery

Con ésta función actualmente estoy metiendo un código para que se ejecute en base a la librería que hemos cargado con la función.

```
$.getScript('url', function() {
   //Función para dicha librería
});
```

Hay alguna forma de modificar el código de forma similar, pero que pueda tener la librería Js cargada en el head bajo sus etiquetas ? Porque lo que me gustaría es que si cargo una librería, afecte a toda la web y no solo meter un trocito de código dentro de la función con la que la llamamos... Se que puede no tener sentido pero para una aplicación (mAuthor) no hay otra forma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ejecutar un script cualquiera en tu página solo necesitas agregar un nuevo elemento `script` en el head del documento y este lo cargará y ejecutará siguendo las mismas reglas que aplican cuando cargas tus scripts iniciales. Esto aplica para todo el documento.

```js
var s = $('script');
var libreria = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js';
s.attr('src', libreria);
$(document.head).append(s);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Un equivalente también puede ser

```
var libreria = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js';
$(document.head).append('<script src=" + libreria +"></script>');
```

El equivalente en javascript puro es

```js
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js';
document.head.appendChild(script);
```

Lee la referencia del elemento [`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/script)

> El Elemento HTML Script (`<script>`) es usado para incrustar o referenciar un script ejecutable en un documento HTML o XHTML.
>
> Scripts sin los atributos `async` o `defer` asi como los scripts incrustados son cargados y ejecutados inmediatamente, antes que el navegador continúe interpretando la página.

Comment: También utilicé éste, que es idéntico y "fácil" de leer. Mil gracias!.


$('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/5361518150942720.js"></script>');

Comment: @djohny Si, son básicamente lo mismo. Si ves que el ejemplo me quedó un poco ilegible es porque los snippets de stackoverflow tienen algunas limitaciones de seguridad para cargar los scripts así que hay que *trucarlos* un poco para que funcione. Suerte ;)

Comment: Si, gracias por tus respuestas! asi da gusto jeje:)